# Are there any scripts derived from Chinese characters that diverged before Regular Script?

Tags: writing-systems, chinese

The Wikipedia article on [clerical script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script) lists several child systems such as Kanji, Kana, Hanja, Zhuyin, Sawndip, Chữ Hán etc. Are there any writing systems descended from seal script or earlier?

Comment: I don't think the article suggests all other systems such as Kanji and Hanja are specifically descendants of the clerical script..? Clerical script is just one established style of writing Chinese characters, similar to Fraktur for the Latin alphabet. Kanji/Hanja can be written in any style including clerical script / seal script / etc.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_family_of_scripts#Scripts_influenced_by_Chinese